# Whats the difference between hibernate.connection.autocommit and hibernate.c3p0.autocommit?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have following bean:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql">
                <value>${hibernate.show_sql}</value>
            </property>
            <property name="generateDdl">
                <value>${generateDdl}</value>
            </property>
            <property name="databasePlatform">
                <value>${databasePlatform}</value>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">${hibernate.connection.autocommit}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.archive.autodetection">${hibernate.archive.autodetection}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.comment_sql">${hibernate.comment_sql}</prop>

            <!-- optimization settings -->
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">${hibernate.max_fetch_depth}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">${hibernate.jdbc.batch_size}</prop>

            <!-- c3p0 connection pool settings -->
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">${hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">${hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">${hibernate.c3p0.timeout}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime">${hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">${hibernate.c3p0.min_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">${hibernate.c3p0.max_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">${hibernate.c3p0.max_statements}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_pool_size">${hibernate.c3p0.min_pool_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_pool_size">${hibernate.c3p0.max_pool_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">${hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod">${hibernate.c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.autocommit">${hibernate.c3p0.autocommit}</prop>

            <!-- second level cache settings -->
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">${hibernate.cache.provider_class}</prop>
            <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">${net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_query_cache}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Can anyone explain to me whats the difference between `hibernate.connection.autocommit` and `hibernate.c3p0.autocommit`? Also there are another equal properties . Whats the difference? Also what happens if they are different which one will prevail?

Answer (score 0):

According to the c3p0 documentation :

> `autoCommitOnClose` Must be set in c3p0.properties, C3P0 default: false
>
> The JDBC spec is unfortunately silent on what should happen to unresolved, pending transactions on Connection close. C3P0's default policy is to rollback any uncommitted, pending work. (I think this is absolutely, undeniably the right policy, but there is no consensus among JDBC driver vendors.) Setting autoCommitOnClose to true causes uncommitted pending work to be committed, rather than rolled back on Connection close.

As `hibernate.c3o0.autocommit` drives this settings, we can say that the difference is that `hibernate.connection.autocommit` is just like wrapping every query with `begin transaction;` and then `commit`.

Both are not recommended.